# Can I backup and restore firewall settings on win 8.1?

Tags: networking, windows-8.1, firewall

Can I backup and restore the firewall whitelist on windows 8.1, independently of any other system settings??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

> **Netsh advfirewall** is a command-line tool for Windows Firewall with Advanced Security that helps with the creation, administration, and monitoring of Windows Firewall and IPsec settings and provides an alternative to console-based management.
>
> <sub>Source: [Netsh Commands for Windows Firewall with Advanced Security](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771920%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)</sub>

### Backup

1. Open an [elevated command prompt](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/command-prompt-faq#1TC=windows-8).
2. Type or paste the following command, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

   ```
   netsh advfirewall export "%userprofile%\Desktop\FirewallPolicy.wfw"
   ```

   The file should be saved on the desktop.

### Restore

1. Open an elevated command prompt.
2. Type or paste the following command, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

   ```
   netsh advfirewall import "X:\Path\to\FirewallPolicy.wfw"
   ```

### Further reading

- [Netsh Commands for Windows Firewall with Advanced Security](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771920%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)
- [Windows Firewall with Advanced Security Overview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831365.aspx)